# Not getting proper value after round off with parseFloat

Tags: javascript, math

I am rounding off a value. See below..

console.log(parseFloat(parseFloat(0.670).toFixed(3)));

I am getting 0.67 for this, but expected one is 0.670 as per mathematical rule. And i know why this is.. this is because i am converting it into float.

Problem is that I have to convert it into float, please help me to get proper one.

Comment: I'm getting `0.670` in firefox?

Comment: I'm getting  0.670 in chrome?

Comment: Aren't 0.67 and 0.670 the same number??? What you want is to format the output with 3 decimals...

Comment: And is funny that you already do that

Comment: Even IE calculates it as 0.670

Comment: which version of firefox and chrome you are using. @EmilS.Jørgensen.

Comment: @JyotilRaval Version `50.0`.

Comment: Come on... Nobody is realizing he is passing a number as parameter to parseFloat? (wich has to receive a string)

Comment: U guys not understood the problem.. i want to convert it into parseFloat which removes 0 from the end.. See parseFloat((0.6699).toString()).toFixed(3).. this will give you 0.670 in string.
But i want it in float.

Comment: @Vi100 It's not a problem here, because a types coercion has occured

Comment: This is what i am trying.. parseFloat(parseFloat(0.670).toFixed(3)) try this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log(parseFloat(0.670).toFixed(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

`var num = 0.670;` is completely equal to `var num = 0.67;`

It is impossible for a float variable to remember its significant digits. You will have to keep track of its precision manually.

There is no harm in showing the number as a string after calculations are done. `console.log(num.toFixed(3));` > `0.670`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I read the question correctly.

```js
function toPrecision(num, length = 0) {
  const numArr = num.toString().split('')
  const index = numArr.indexOf('.')
  const decimal = index > -1 ? index + 1 : 0
  return Number(numArr.slice(0, decimal + length).join(''))
}

console.log(
  toPrecision(0.6699, 0),
  toPrecision(0.6699, 1),
  toPrecision(0.6699, 2),
  toPrecision(0.6699, 3),
  toPrecision(10006688.669966, 4)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var a = parseFloat(parseFloat(0.6699).toFixed(3)) + "<br>";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```